# Regular expression or string parsing for nested brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string-parsing

Consider the following string as input. The second & third AND are redundant. I want to removed it.

Input

```
 AND(AND(string("test message")),filter(AND(OR(source:string("XYZ"),source:string("ABC")))))
```

I want the output as

```
 AND(string("test message"),filter(OR(source:string("XYZ"),source:string("ABC"))))
```

Basically the input string has AND operator used, but there is only one argument specified, this makes the input a invalid string. I want to modify the string to remove AND such that it has only one argument specified in it.

What should be the best approach. Regular expression or string parsing. My string can be very long.

I checked multiple posts & seems like regular expression is not recommended especially if it is too much nested.

Please suggest the best way to handle this case.

Some input & their output

1.
    AND(string(""test message""))

```
string(""test message"")
```

1. AND(AND(string(""test message"")),filter(AND(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC"")))))

   AND(string(""test message""),filter(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC""))))
2. AND(string(""test message""),filter(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC"")))) 
    AND(string(""test message""),filter(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC""))))

Annu

Comment: you only want the second and third `AND` to be removed ? nothing more or less?

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to remove the associated parenthesis?

Comment: @sshashank124 - yes I want to remove the associated parenthesis

Comment: In that case, I doubt you can do that with just `regex`. You'll need a specialized function for this very purpose

Comment: @aelor - there can be N AND operators used in the string. Basically I want to find out the AND operator which have only one argument. Here is the input string second and third AND are invalid as it has only one input

Answer (score 1):

If you go the regex route then a positive lookahead followed by a negative lookahead could work:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(searchText, "(?i)(?x)(?(?<!AND\\()AND\\()|(?(?=\\){2})(?!\\){3})\\))", "");
```

Input:

```
AND(AND(string("test message")),filter(AND(OR(source:string("XYZ"),source:string("ABC")))))

AND(string(""test message""))

AND(string(""test message""),filter(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC""))))
```

Result:

```
AND(string("test message"),filter(OR(source:string("XYZ"),source:string("ABC"))))

string(""test message"")

string(""test message""),filter(OR(source:string(""XYZ""),source:string(""ABC"")))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but for specific input. Basically I want to validate user input. Consider this string AND(string(""test message"")) . This is a invalid string because, AND is used by two values are not mentioned, I want to remove such AND operator/string. so the output would be string(""test message""). Can you please give the regular expression for it

Comment: it's simple - you can use the pattern I've created and modify it to your hearts content. `(AND\\()|(?=\\){2})\\)` would result in `string(""test message"")`. Notice I've changed the `AND` slightly by shifting the `(` and removed the conditional positive/negative lookahead. The pattern is essentially [this](http://regex101.com/r/jH9bA6), but modified for C#. Play around with it and you should quickly get an idea of how it works; the magic formula for your original question is really in the conditional positive/negative lookahead that I've used. The 2nd example is just a couple pieces of it.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://regex101.com/r/bH4iB6) you can work with regarding your first question. Switch `AND` in the pattern with `THIS` and you'll notice how it handles the additional expression. The difference in patterns is that in C# it's necessary to use two `\\` escape characters instead of one.

Comment: it removed all AND, my requirement is different, when I specify AND then there may or may not be two or more argument passed to it, if there is only one argument then I want to remove AND, if there are two or more argument passed then do not want to do anything

Comment: Added some input output, please check the original question

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I fully understand your logic, although I've updated my answer; It should handle the multiple patterns you've added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried it in tcl , this is the soultion

regsub -all {\(AND} $string "" string .u will get the expected output
```

Comment: thanks for your response, Can you the regular expression which I can use with C#

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# but just check regex.replace command and try